# Поймать get c помощью js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть страница на которой необходимо поймать GET запрос и если передается `id = ..`, то показывать блок ,а если не то скрывать. Необходимо это сделать с помощью `JS`.

Comment: А что вы собираетесь делать с id после того как отловили?)

Comment: @Damon Haswell, просто необходимо скрывать или показывать блок редактирования. Если есть `id` то показываем блок редактирования. Согласен, тупо, не логично, главное работает! И быстрее сделаю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам ничего не нужно "ловить". Со стороны JS доступен URL страницы, в котором будут GET параметры. Просто разберите их из `location.search`

Answer (score 2):

Перехватывать - идея странная, но возможная через подмену некоторых функций:

```js
function GEThandler(obj){
  console.info("GET Request has been requested");
}

let _XMLHttpRequestOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(...args){
  if(args[0].toLowerCase() === 'get') GEThandler(this);
  _XMLHttpRequestOpen.apply(this, args);
}

let _fetch = fetch;
fetch = function(...args){
  let config = args[1];
  
  if(config === undefined || (typeof config === 'object' && 'method' in config && (config.method + '').toLowerCase() === 'get'))
    GEThandler(this);

  _fetch.apply(this, args);
}


// XMLHttpRequest
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', true);
xhr.send();


// fetch
fetch('/');
```